# Warning using \recalctypearea after \spacing

Tags: latex

I use `DIV=10` to set the type area, because the calculated type area would have too large margins for me.
I have read that you should use `\recalctypearea` after setting the font and line spacing. 
So first: does this also make sense, when I have a defined DIV-value instead of `DIV=calc`?

If yes, here is my actual question: I use `\spacing{1.2}`, because `\onehalfspacing` seems to be a little bit too large for me. 
I get the warning "`Package typearea Warning: \typearea used at group level 2. Using \typearea inside any group, e.g. environments, math mode, boxes, etc. may result in many type setting problems. You should move the command \typearea outside all groups on input line 11.`"
If I use `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` instead of `\usepackage{setspace} \spacing{1.2}`, I don't get this warning.

Should I ignore the warning or what should I do?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headinclude=false, footinclude=false,  BCOR=8mm,DIV=10]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common},Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine Mono O}

\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.2} 

\recalctypearea

\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Package typearea

The command `\recalctypearea` ist just an abbreviation for `\typearea[current]{last}` which means, that the page layout is calculated again by the current binding correction (BCOR, first parameter) and the last DIV value (second parameter), see [KOMA-script documentation p. 37](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#37)

The BCOR and DIV value must be set beforehand. But, all (normal) ways to set these options already do a page layout calculation afterwards. So, if you want `DIV=10`, then use one of the following ways:

```
% Choosing a KOMA-script class
\documentclass[DIV=10]{scrreport}

% During loading the package, if another documentclass is used
\usepackage[DIV=10]{typearea}

% Or after loading the package with one of these
% a)
\KOMAoptions{DIV=10}

% b)
\typearea{10}
```

So, `\recalctypearea` should only be required if `DIV=calc` has been used and fonts or page sizes have been changed since this option has been set the last time.

#### Interaction with package spacing

Setting the `DIV` parameter affects the whole page. So, you can't change it within a group, e.g. the itemize environment `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}`.

Calling `\spacing{1.2}` opens a new group (environment) which is closed by `\endspacing`. The spacing will only be changed within this environment. Something which cannot be done (normally) for the page layout. Don't ignore the warning. To change the line spacing, use the macro `\linespread` instead, e.g.:

```
\linespread{1.25} % within preamble
```

should give a line spacing of 1.2*1.25 = 1.5. (1.2 is the normal base line skip). For more information see [also here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141317).

#### Further hints

Please note, that direct calls of `\spacing` macros is not recommended. Use

```
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
Your Text
\end{spacing}
```

instead because `\end{spacing}` will check if the right environment is closed (better error reporting).

For some details, here is the code of the `spacing` environment:

```
% quote from setspace.sty, line 524 ff, fetched from CTAN at 2015-11-17
\newenvironment{spacing}[1]{%
  \par
  \begingroup             % moved from \endspacing by PGBR 29-1-91
    \setstretch {#1}%
}{%
  \restore@spacing
}
```

The first code block

```
{%
  \par
  \begingroup             % moved from \endspacing by PGBR 29-1-91
    \setstretch {#1}%
}
```

is called at `\begin{spacing}{...}` and starts a new paragraph (`\par`) and opens a new group (`\begingroup`). Within a group, changes to LaTeX variables/ macros (and so on) will only have a local effect. The second code block is called at `\end{spacing}` which calls an appropiate `\endgroup`.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure: In my case I should omit `\recalctypearea`, because I don't use `DIV=calc`. Furthermore I should use `\linespread{1.2}` instead of `\spacing{1.2}` (to get a line spacing of 1.44). Right?